# Roll Up Error: Unexpected token: name

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I am trying to use Rollup to bundle and treeshake my existing project. However, I'm getting the following error.

> Export 'Client' is not defined by 'C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\docs\client\service\search.service.js'
>   Error transforming bundle with 'uglify' plugin: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (UiService)

here is my search.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch';
//declare var elasticsearch: any;

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    private Client: elasticsearch.Client;
    constructor() {
        var connectionString = 'https://paas:2664f39b6a927d0873b43fab6893ace6@bifur-eu-west-1.searchly.com';
        this.Client = new elasticsearch.Client({
            host: connectionString,
            log: 'trace'
        });
    }

    search(term: string): any {
        return this.Client.search({
            index: 'plugins',
            type: 'ds044699_mlab_com_cdc1',
            body: {
                query: {
                    multi_match: {
                        query: term,
                        fields: ['name', 'description']
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is my ui.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UiService {
    chapters: string;
    // Observable boolean streams
    navState$ = this.navStateSource.asObservable();
    chapter = this._chapter.asObservable();

    // Observable boolean sources
    private navStateSource = new Subject<boolean>();
    private _chapter: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

    // Service message commands
    changeNavState(showNav: boolean) {
        this.navStateSource.next(showNav);
    }

    changeChapter(chapter: number) {
        this._chapter.next(chapter);
    }
}
```

I can't see what is wrong with either of these files? - Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 3):

For the first error (`Export 'Client' is not defined by...`), you probably need to use the `namedExports` option with [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs#custom-named-exports). We've just released a new version of Rollup that makes this message a bit more self-explanatory and links to the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module) page.

The second message looks like it's probably related to UglifyJS not minifying ES6 code. You might need to target ES5 in your TypeScript configuration (I think – I don't do TypeScript) or add a transform like [rollup-plugin-buble](https://gitlab.com/Rich-Harris/rollup-plugin-buble) or [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel) to convert it to ES5 before minification.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I am compiling this into an es2015 style module with TypeScript, you can see the compiler options [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/blob/performance/client/tsconfig-aot.json) - so it shouldn't be a commonJS module?